# Ubuntu Linux complete freeze on multi-core load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, cpu, freeze

I got a problem with my computer freezing I have not been able to resolve. The system spec's are as follows:

- AMD FX6300
- ASRock 970 Extreme3 R2.0
- 2x Kingston KHX1600C9D3/4GX
- BeQuiet Straight Power 500W

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. As soon as I start tasks which are CPU as well as RAM intensive, the whole system freezes. I can easily reproduce the error through starting an OpenFOAM simulation job in parallel mode.

Usually the computer is controlled via SSH. As soon as I start the task, in a matter of seconds, at most minutes, the system becomes uncontrollable. Also ping requests from other computers stop getting returned as soon as the freeze happens. For testing purposes I fitted the system with a GPU and noticed, that I do not get a crash but a complete system freezes - the screen just freezes and I am not able to input any command either via keyboard or mouse.

In terms of troubleshooting I already tried:

- running Memtest --> 4 runs without any problems
- testing the RAM sticks each individually in different slots
- re-applying cooling paste on the CPU
- disconnecting the GPU

syslog and faillog didn't turn up anything concerning either.

Any ideas on further troubleshooting?

Comment: Monitor/log the temps? Vents & fans are all clean & working? Could try throttling down the max cpu frequency for testing (cpufreq-utils if supported, I think there's another similar utility too)?

Comment: CPU temps seemed to be fine (maxed out during ~60°C in prime95 **before** repasting) - the CPU throtteling approach sounds reasonable, I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: Set CPU max to 2.5GHz and had a freeze after just a couple of seconds running OpenFOAM on three cores. So neither frequency nor temperature seem to have an influence (I highly doubt higher temperatures than ~20°C after 10 seconds of running)

Comment: That's one issue down... I'd try a different kernel & distribution, a live ISO (USB/DVD) is easy to make & install to the live system (if there's enough ram) & test. Maybe a newer/older Ubuntu, or Debian, or a different "family" like opensuse, fedora, etc. Next idea would be the power supply

Comment: Could you give some details about the OpenFOAM case? E.g.: - Does it run in serial? - What OpenFOAM version? - How many cells? - What solver? - How are you calling the parallelised solver? (mpirun, mpiexec..?)